# JavaScript, passing id as parameter to function

Tags: javascript, html

I have `<td>` with an Id `<td id="firstApp">`. I have write onclick event for button. when button is clicked `showDate` function iscalled. I want to pass 'id' as parameter to this showDate function so my function will get to know on which id it should act.

I tried,

```
<td><button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("firstApp").innerHTML=Date()'>
```

Then it works fine.

But when I pass id as function call,

```
<td><button type="button" onclick='showDate("firstApp")'>
```

Then it won't work, can anybody tell me where I went wrong...!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <tr>
            <td>App 1</td>
            <td><button type="button" onclick='showDate("firstApp")' name="app1" >on/off</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td id="firstApp"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <!--    <button type="button">Update</button> <button type="button">Log Out</button> -->
        </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            //write script herei
            function showDate(appId)
            {

                document.getElementById("appId").innerHTML = Date();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to put quotes around the argument when using it:

```
function showDate(appId) {
    document.getElementById(appId).innerHTML = Date();
    // No quotes here ------^----^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>App 1</td>
            <td><button type="button" onclick='showDate("firstApp")' name="app1" >on/off</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td id="firstApp"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <!--    <button type="button">Update</button> <button type="button">Log Out</button> -->
        </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            //write script herei
            function showDate(appId)
            {

                document.getElementById(appId).innerHTML = Date();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Remove quote from **appId**

```
document.getElementById(appId).innerHTML = Date();
```